# Map array of objects and change one property with a function that calls an API. I keep getting promise pending

Tags: javascript, async-await, javascript-objects

I have to loop through an array of objects and modify one single property in each object. I modify this property with a function that connects to the Twitter API. My problem is that I must be using async and await wrongly because I am getting a promise pending.

This is my code:

```
getProfile:(req,res)=>{
        try {
           const userId=req.params.id 
           const profile=db.query('SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user_id=?',
        [userId],async (err,result)=>{

            if(err) return res.status(404).send(err)

            const profiles= await result.map(  obj=>{

                const container={}
                container['name']=obj.profile_name
                container['desc']=obj.profile_desc
                container['twitter']=  connectTwitt.getTwitt(obj.twitt)//calls to api
                return  container
            })
            console.log(profiles)// promise pending
            res.send(profiles)
```

This is the structure of the array of object that I am mapping:

```
[
 {profile_name:`Elon Musk`, profile_desc:'enterpreneur',twitt:636465}
]
```

Comment: `connectTwitt.getTwitt(obj.twitt)`, does this return anything? Do you need to await on this line?

Comment: You can't await `.map` method. Alternatively you can use for loop to iterate result from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are using the `async`/`await` syntax a little bit incorrectly.

Right now, you are calling `await` on the `Array.map()` method. However, that method is not promise-based.

Instead, you have to add the `await` keyword to the `getTwitt()` method, and `await` for all promises to complete.

With those changes, it should look like below.

```js
const profiles = await Promise.all(result.map(async (obj) => { // This line has been modified
  const container = {};
  container["name"] = obj.profile_name;
  container["desc"] = obj.profile_desc;
  container["twitter"] = await connectTwitt.getTwitt(obj.twitt); // This line has been modified.
  return container;
}));
```

Hopefully this helps with your `<pending>` issue!

Comment: The function isn't declared `async`, you can't use `await` inside it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929347/why-is-my-function-returning-promise-pending?noredirect=1#comment113047163_63929347

Comment: Now I guess OPs next question will be how they can convert the array of Promises stored in `profiles` to an array of objects.

Comment: Thank you Promise.all worked and solved the issue. I just had to add async to the first callback function.